# How do i get docker/ nginx to mount on my index file

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to containerise and run my website on a PHP webserver with an nginx conf file (site.conf) and docker-compose.yml file. When I go to `localhost:8080` I get the default nginx welcome page instead of the my index.html file. and When I go to `php-docker.local:8080` I get a "this site cannot be reached message".

**Code Section**

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <title>Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />


    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body class="container">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Registration</h1>
      <section>
        <form id="regForm" action="form.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nameInput">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput" name="studentName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter your full name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="loginInput">Login</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="loginInput" name="studentId"  placeholder="Enter your login">
          </div>

          
          <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitForm">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
    
    

    
    <script src="js/regForm.js"></script>
    <!-- Datatable -->
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.startbootstrap.com/sb-forms-latest.js"></script> -->
    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php


echo "Submitted";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$data = '';
$filename = "data.json";
//if file exists
if(is_file($filename)) {
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);
}

$json_arr = json_decode($data,true);

$json_arr[] = array(
    'studentId' => $_POST['studentId'],
    'studentName' => $_POST['studentName'],
    
);

file_put_contents($filename, json_encode($json_arr));

}

?>
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - php
  php:
    image: php:7-fpm
```

site.conf (nginx conf file)

```
server {
    index index.html;
    server_name php-docker.local;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /src;
}
```

**file/folder structure**

```
-form
  -src
    -index.html
    -form.php
  -docker-compose.yml
  -site.conf
```

*** localhost Output ***
localhost:8080

[image: localhost:8080]

php-docker.local:8080

[image: php-docker.local:8080]

Comment: Have you added the hostname `php-docker.local` to your hosts file?

Comment: No, how do i do that?

Comment: what is a host file and can anybody please help me on how I can do this?

Comment: Are you on Windows? Then `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. You need an entry to route the hostname: `php-docker.local 127.0.0.1`